# Greatest common divisor algorithm implied theorem need prove

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Please help me prove this
"An integer is a linear combination of a and b if and only if it is a multiple of their greatest common divisor."
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $LaTeX$ syntax. This appears to be a [homework question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question), please share your thoughts and attempts towards the solution. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

The only non-trivial point is to prove $\gcd(a,b)$ is a linear combination, with integer coefficients, of $a$ and $b$. To prove it, you can prove *more*: in the *Euclidean algorithm*, at each step, the remainder is such a linear combination. Use (finite) induction for this. A careful examination of what happens gives you the *extended Euclidean algorithm*.

Answer (score 0):

Note: If the coefficients of the linear combination of $c$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ are integers, this could be written as
$$
a \, X + b \, Y = c
$$
which is a linear Diophantine equation.

The criterion for solutions is $d \mid c$, with $d = \gcd(a, b)$.